# Circuits and Power

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

"The diagram below represents a simple circuit composed of 5 identical light bulbs and 2 flashlight batteries. Which bulb (or bulbs) would you expect to be the brightest?

[image]

a) V only

b) V and W only

c) V and Z only

d) V, W, and Z only

e) all five bulbs are the same brightness"

The solutions say the answer is d, but I'm wondering if someone can explain why. I know X and Y have the same brightness because they're in parallel, but I don't understand why it's lower than the others. (I'd prefer an intuitive answer rather than one that makes reference to formulas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it in terms of current, V, W, and Z are in series, so each is equally bright. X and Y are in parallel, so each gets half the current of the others. If you assume each bulb is a constant resistance R (not true for incandescent bulbs, by the way), then V,W and Z will each dissipate $i^2R$. For X and Y, since each has a current i/2, the power will be 1/4 that of the others.

Comment: So really it's because of the amount of current going through each? The ones in series have the same current and thus the same power dissipation, while the parallel ones have a reduced current and thus less dissipation. Thanks for the answer!